# Bash environment variable setting of 'HOME' returns "pyenv: no such command `sh-activate'"

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pyenv

My questions is about pyenv a python version control manager and bash script.

I have been running a bash script to run multiple dropbox account on my Ubuntu system. (reference link: https://askubuntu.com/a/475420 )

After I set up pyenv and autoenv, I found out a command in my bash script return a error message as below.

command) `HOME="$HOME/.dropbox-alt"`

returns) `pyenv: no such command`sh-activate'`

The environment variable above seems work well.
when I run a command, echo $HOME, it returns as below.

command) `echo $HOME`

returns)

```
 /home/myname/.dropbox-alt
    pyenv: no such command `sh-activate'
```

And this error message comes along with all bash commands such as, commandexport, ls, cd, mkdir, ...

Here is my `~/.bashrc` ends with,

#Load pyenv automatically by adding

#the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/home/june/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"

eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

source ~/.autoenv/activate.sh
```

---

I am wondering what makes this error message and am wondering whether if this error affect any of my system.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you show your bashrc?

Comment: Now it seems to work fine after I set up all my dropbox accounts. I have been running with no error for a couple of months.

Answer (score 4):

install pyenv-virtualenv
if you use macOS run this code

```bash
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

Comment: Should add some context to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.